# Knockout Custom Extender not working

Tags: knockout.js, typescript

I have searched and tested multiple examples.  All of the examples I have seen work in JSFiddler but the moment I put them into my Typescript files nothing happens.  I am missing something but for the life of me I cannot figure out what it is I am missing.

Nothing happens and in fact if I put break points on the extender in the DevTools of Chrome, they are NEVER hit.

** Taken Directly from Knockoutjs.com with one slight modification, I dropped the second parameter and just hardcoded it to 2**

Extenders.ts

```
    ko.extenders.currency = function(target) {
        var result = ko.pureComputed({
            read : target,
            write : function(newValue) {
                var current = target(),
                    roundingMultipler = Math.pow(10, 2),
                    newValueAsNum = isNaN(+newValue) ? 0 : parseFloat(newValue.toString()),
                    valueToWrite = Math.round(newValueAsNum * roundingMultipler) / roundingMultipler;

                if (valueToWrite !== current) {
                    target(valueToWrite);
                }
                else {
                    if (newValue !== current) {
                        target.notifySubscribers(valueToWrite);
                    }
                }
            }
        }).extend({ notify: 'always' });

        result(target());
        return result;
    }
```

My ViewModel

```
    this.productPrice = ko.observable(null)
        .extend({
            currency : true,
            required : { message : 'A Product Price is required.' }
        });
```

Comment: In the HTML document, how are you loading the javascript files? Is Extenders.js loaded before the javascript file containing your ViewModel?

Comment: yes, the Extenders.js is before the ViewModel.  The VM is the very last thing I load.

Comment: It works fine for me. https://gist.github.com/cascadian/5c0ec685a7533b3b8ec6

Comment: Thanks.  I just needed a second pair of eyes.  While I was downloading the files in the right order, I was not initializing them in the correct order.

Comment: Please turn your comment into answer if problem is solved! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with my code was had the initializer calls (to setup my extenders) after I had called the constructor on my ViewModel.

I have since moved all my initializers for my prototypes, validations, extenders, and BindingHanders to a new SiteMaster script that is ALWAYS the first thing to fire off when the page loads up.